# iPhone View Sliding effect - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What is the event in iPhone development to write code to a slide left and slide right operation.

As in when you slide the view of your phone, you go into another view. What is the event that i should write my code ?

Comment: What if you don't know what to search ?

Comment: You do, though. You mentioned a slide operation. If you don't know what to search, then you probably don't have enough information to ask a clearly defined question on here, either. Try searching for something more generic. In fact, I only just realised what you were actually asking. I'll post an answer anyway.

Comment: A bit of irony on the do-a-search idea: this page is the top Google hit for me when I search using the terms "transitionFromView slide".

Answer (score 1):

The event you are looking to catch is called a `swipe`. Apple provides a [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to handle this for you. Implementation advice can be found in the [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) section of the Event Handling Guide for iOS.

Briefly, you create the recognizer:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer =
[[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)] autorelease];
```

Then set how many fingers the swipe is, and what direction it needs to be in:

```
swipeGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2; // default is 1
// allow swiping either left or right, default is right only
swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft |
                                   UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
```

And then add it to your view:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];
```

When the user swipes, your `swipe:` method will get called.

Answer (score 1):

Darvids0n covered a gesture to slide the view out. I interpreted the question as an animation to slide the view out, in which case you'll want UIView's `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` class method:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:view1 toView:view2 duration:1.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft) completion:NULL];
```

This actually gives you a curl. If you want a slide, you'll have to code a custom animation. Check out UIView's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and especially the '[animateWithDuration:animations:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a)' class method.

Comment: +1 animation was my original thought too (see comments on the question), but I read this "when you slide the view of your phone, you go into another view" and took that as sliding a finger and that triggering a gesture recognizer which then performs a slide animation to go into another view. So I think we're both right, actually :)

Comment: Then again, Shyta could also mean having a gesture recognizer that recognizes a pan and follows the finger. A pan/swipe combo? The plot thickens…